# Unsure about step in Ford's explanation of Cramer' Probabilistic Model for Primes

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Kevin Ford in his slides on prime gaps explains how the simple idea that primes occurs with probability $1/\log(x)$ can be used to construct a probabilistic model for prime gaps.

source: [https://conf.math.illinois.edu/~ford/montreal_talk1_primegaps.pdf](https://conf.math.illinois.edu/%7Eford/montreal_talk1_primegaps.pdf)

On slide 6 (reproduced below) he explains that the probability of a prime gap of size $g$ is

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{\log(x)} \right)^g$$

This makes sense if we assume the probability of a number being prime is independent of another.

He then says this is

$$\approx e^{g/\log N}$$

**Question: I don't understand how this is N and not $k$.**

I'd welcome answers that are suitable for readers not trained to university maths.

---

[image]